# Beginner help on overloading construtors and methods

Tags: java

I'm writing code for school that requires 3 classes (Main, Airport, Coordinates).  Airport calculates the distance between two airports.  Originally it was 2 classes (Main, Airport).  Where doubles are input by the user in Main class and passed through a distanceCalc method in the Airport class.  The Coordinates class is added to hold the Latitude and Longitude values instead, and we have to use overloaded constructors and methods in the Airport class to pass the values through the distanceCalc method.

The problem I'm having is when I call the distanceCalc method that accepts a class argument it is using the SAME Latitude and Longitude values for both Airports and returning 0.0 as the distance between them.  Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help me figure out why.  Here are pieces of the code where it takes place.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Variable Declaration
    Airport Airport1, Airport2;
    Scanner objKB = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat objFmt = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.0");
    double Lat1, Long1, Lat2, Long2, nautMiles, statueMiles;
    String depAirport, arrAirport;
    Coordinates coord = new Coordinates();

    // User Inputs
    System.out.println("Enter three digit airport ID of departing airport: ");
    depAirport = objKB.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter three digit airport ID of arriving airport: ");
    arrAirport = objKB.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter latitude of departing airport: ");
    Lat1 = objKB.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter longitude of departing airport: ");
    Long1 = objKB.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter latitude of arriving airport: ");
    Lat2 = objKB.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter longitude of arriving airport: ");
    Long2 = objKB.nextDouble();

    Airport1 = new Airport(Lat1, Long1);
    Airport2 = new Airport(Lat2, Long2);

    //Calculations from Airport class
    nautMiles = Airport.getDistance(Lat1, Long1, Lat2, Long2); //original method that calculates properly
    nautMiles = Airport1.getDistance(Airport2); //new method that will calculate 0.0
```

Airport Class:

```
public class Airport {
    public static double getDistance(double Lat1, double Long1, double Lat2, double Long2) {

    // Local Variable Declaration
    double distance;
    double greatCircle;
    double radius = 10800 / Math.PI; 

    //Calculations
    Lat1 = Math.toRadians(Lat1);
    Long1 = Math.toRadians(Long1);
    Lat2 = Math.toRadians(Lat2);
    Long2 = Math.toRadians(Long2);
    greatCircle = Math.acos(Math.sin(Lat1) * Math.sin(Lat2) + Math.cos(Lat1) * Math.cos(Lat2) 
            * Math.cos(Long1 - Long2));
    distance = radius * greatCircle;

    //Return
    return distance;
}
// Method overloads

public double getDistance(Airport a){
    double lat1, lat2, long1, long2;
    lat1 = coord.getLat();
    long1 = coord.getLong();
    lat2 = a.getLat();
    long2 = a.getLong();
    return getDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2);
    }

public double getDistance(Coordinates c){
    double lat1, long1, lat2, long2;
    lat1 = coord.getLat();
    long1 = coord.getLong();
    lat2 = c.getLat();
    long2 = c.getLong();
    return getDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2);
    }

public double getDistance(double lat, double lng){
    double lat2, long2;
    lat2 = coord.getLat();
    long2 = coord.getLong();
    return getDistance(lat, lng, lat2, long2);
    }

    //Fields
    private Coordinates coord;

    //Constructors
    public Airport() {
        coord = new Coordinates();          
    }

    public Airport(double Latitude, double Longitude){
        this();
        coord.setLat(Latitude);
        coord.setLong(Longitude);   
    }

    public Airport(Coordinates values){
        this(values.getLat(), values.getLong());    
    }

    //Mutators and Accessors
    public double getLat() {return coord.getLat();}
    public void setLat(double lat) {
        coord.setLat(lat);
    }

    public double getLong() {return coord.getLong();}
    public void setLong(double lng) {
        coord.setLong(lng);
    }
```

Coordinates class

```
public class Coordinates {

//Fields
private static double Latitude, Longitude;

//Mutators and Accessors
public double getLat() {return Latitude;}
public void setLat(double lat) {
    Latitude = lat;
}

public double getLong() {return Longitude;}
public void setLong(double lng) {
    Longitude = lng;
}

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve].

Comment: Your code is full of gaps that could be critical to your question, for all we know. If you presume to know where the bug is located, why waste our time?

Comment: Let us see your `Coordinates` class and the calculations you make in `distanceCalc`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Sorry I tried to condense so there less to read but I guess that made it impossible to answer.  There are outputs in the Main class but that's not the issue.  It occurs on the last line of the Main i posted.  I used debug but I have little knowledge debugging.  I see that Airport1 and Airport2 have different values but when that method `Airport1.getDistance(Airport2)` executes it assigns Lat2 and Long2 to both sets of doubles in the method.  I can't figure out why.  So i know the location but not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here: `private static double Latitude, Longitude;`
By making this `static`, it means every instance of coordinate has the same latitude and longitude.
Making something static means all instances of a class will share the same data.

Comment: Holy crap what a stupid easy fix!  thx!!!  I've been editing the methods and constructors which mostly just created errors but it was how I declared the variables in the first place.

Comment: sometimes it's the little things :)